# Remove last n chars (including \n \r and ^Z) from the end of a file (with sed)

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a fiel with an awkward file end.

```
cat splitted.0473.csv | tail -c 8 | od -c
0000000   6   4   0  \r  \n 032  \r  \n
0000010
```

The `032` is a `^Z` (know as [substitution character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character)).

I want to remove the last 3 characters (bytes?) from the end of the file so it look like this:

```
cat splitted.0473.csv | tail -c 8 | od -c
0000000   6   4   0  \r  \n
0000010
```

I tried some `sed` examples but didn't succeed. I assume that *removing the last n characters* is easier to realize with `sed` (or anything else) then *replace specific characters `^Z\r\n` from the file end*.

Comment: `truncate -s -3 file.csv` with GNU `truncate` would shorten it by 3 bytes.

Comment: Old Windows editors used to use Ctrl-Z to signal end-of-file (like Ctrl-D in Linux), but they explicitly stored the character in the data file (huh?). You might consider using dos2unix to remove the CR (`\r`) -- they are a frequent source of issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to delete the last line with `sed`:

```
sed -i '$d' splitted.0473.csv
```

-->

```
$ printf '640\r\n\032\r\n' | sed '$d' | od -c
0000000   6   4   0  \r  \n
0000005
```